# Extjs Generating components using JsonStore

Tags: extjs

I need to generate checkbox group based on data from DB, so I fetch this data into JsonStore like that:

```
var itemsInGroup = [];

var valuesStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url: '../../data.json',
    root : 'values',
    fields: ['id',  'name'],
    autoLoad: true,
    listeners: {
        load: function(t, records, options) {
            for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                itemsInGroup.push({
                    name: records[i].name,
                    inputValue: records[i].name
                });
            }
        }
    }

});
valuesStore.load();
```

after that I use those items (itemsInGroup) in checkboxgroup nested in panel on page:

```
...
                {
                    id: 'cbGroupId',
                    xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
                    fieldLabel: 'Directions',
                    items: itemsInGroup
                },  ...
```

but this code causes an error. What do I do wrong?

Comment: I've tried these fixes but it still doesn't work... Actually it seems the problem is that when I pass 'itemsInGroup' to panel checkboxgroup field, it's empty yet. But I can't get why...

Comment: Also found another error. Instead of records[i].<field_name> should be used records[i].data.<field_name>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have next usage:

```
var itemsInGroup = [];

var valuesStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore(/*...*/);
valuesStore.load(); 
for(var item in itemsInGroup)
{
    // do something with item
}
```

Request is executed asynchronously and (as response need some time to be fetched) "load"-listener will be called after processing `itemsInGroup` collection.

You should wrap usage of `itemsInGroup` into some method and call this method from load-listener.

```
var valuesStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    listeners: {
        load: function(t, records, options) {
            var itemsInGroup = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                itemsInGroup.push({
                    name: records[i].name,
                    inputValue: records[i].name
                });
            }
            processItems(itemsInGroup);
        }
    }
});
valuesStore.load();

function processItems(items){
   for(var item in items){/*...*/}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
itemsInGroup.push({
    xtype: 'checkbox',
    name: records[i].name,
    inputValue: records[i].name
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
itemsIngroup.push(new Ext.form.CheckBox({
   xtype: 'checkbox',
    name: records[i].name,
    inputValue: records[i].name,
    checked :  records[i].checked

}));
```

You might need to provide a new instance of the checkbox and not just the config object.  This will ensure that the constructor will initialize the object correctly.

Also, you can use the 'checked' property to initialize a value right away.  I believe it accepts boolean true/false values.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work. It seems that load() for store fires later than Panel with Checkboxgroup is rended. But I don't understand why is that..

Answer (score 0):

Use **defaultType : 'checkbox'** :

```
            {
                id: 'cbGroupId',
                xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
                fieldLabel: 'Directions',
                defaultType: 'checkbox',
                items: itemsInGroup
            }
```

And **boxLabel** for checkbox item:

```
             itemsInGroup.push({
                name: records[i].name,
                inputValue: records[i].name,
                boxLabel : records[i].name
            });
```